# apache server hang when running symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am new in symfony2.1. I am using wamp server (apache 2.2.22 and php
5.3.13).  I have configured everything properly for symfony2.1. but
problem happen when I am  trying to retrieve data from database or submit .
Sometimes its work properly but sometime it doesn’t work and hangup the server. Than I have to
restart the server.

To solve that I have installed apache, php and mysql separately. But
still I am facing the same problem.

Please give me a solution.

Comment: Do you have some information or error messages in your system logs? Or you apache log? and do you have enabled some more extensions in php?

Comment: you have to post your error logs. also are you using app.php ? or app_dev.php ? use app_dev.php and post the error logs here.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. I am using app_dev.php. I got an error msg [Tue Oct 23 15:50:53 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico but when when i created favicon.ico in my root folder.. this error are not showing any more. problem is showing both app.php and app_dev.php